# Number of possible triples of $a^2 - b^2 = c^2 + 2$ such that $a,b,\frac{c}{2} \in \mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

If $a,b,\frac{c}{2} \in \mathbb N$ such that $a^2 – b^2 = c^2 + 2$, then the number of possible triplets $(a, b, c)$ is equal to -

(A) 0

(B) 1

(C) 2

(D) infinite

My approach is as follows

Let $c=2t$

Now $a^2-b^2=4t^2+2$

${a^2} - {b^2} = 4{t^2} + 2 \Rightarrow {t^2} = \frac{{{a^2} - {b^2} - 2}}{4}$

Not able to proceed from here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer A because $a^2-b^2$ must be even, so $a$ and $b$ have the same parity, but then, $a+b$ and $a-b$ will be both even so their product will be a multiple of $4,$ whereas $4t^2+2$ is not.